# How to find lowest common ancestor in binary tree using bottom up recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I am having a hard time understanding how to find lowest common ancestor in binary tree using bottom up recursion.

[HERE](http://techsoluton.blogspot.in/2013/03/find-lowest-common-ancestor-in-binary.html?showComment=1420398477530#c2234752835936207561) is the solution which looks very neat. I tried drying running it on a small tree but no luck.

Can someone please help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm you linked to is reproduced below, in case the link changes:

```
public static Tree findLowestCommonAncestor(Tree root, Tree p, Tree q)
{
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    if (root == p || root == q)
        return root;

    Tree left = findLowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
    Tree right = findLowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);

    if (left != null && right != null)
        return root;

    if (left != null)
        return left;
    else
        return right;
}
```

It works like this. The key observation is that if we consider a node *n* that is an ancestor of *p* and *q*, and ask whether it's the lowest common ancestor, there are basically three possibilities:

1. *p* and *q* are both descendants of the left child of *n*, but not the right child;
2. *p* and *q* are both descendants of the right child of *n*, but not the left child;
3. *p* and *q* are both descendants of both children of *n*.

This is the idea behind the whole algorithm. We start at the root, and work our way down. We recursively find the LCA of *p* and *q* from the left child *l* of the current node, and the right child *r* of the current node.

If the left-hand search returns something, but the right-hand search doesn't, then that means the left-hand search found the right value (because the answer is lower down than the current node, and either *l* itself or a descendant of *l*). Similarly if the right-hand search returns something, but the left-hand search doesn't.

If the left-hand and right-hand searches both return something, then *p* and *q* are both descendants of *n*. That means that we can return *n* as the LCA: it can't be anything lower, because otherwise we'd have found it earlier in the recursive search; and it is a common ancestor, so it must therefore be the lowest one.

(The language isn't particularly helpful, by the way: I'd have said that the ancestor you want is the *highest* one in the tree, but in what you're looking at, *lowest* seems to mean *nearest to the root*.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am still struggling when I try to do a dry run on paper. Is there anything you would like to suggest to help with that. :(

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to do this non-recursively. Any ideas?

Comment: @pete : non-recursive solution
`Node LCA(Node n1, Node n2, Node CA){
 while(true){
  if(n1.val<CA.val & n2.val<CA.val) CA=CA.left;
  else if (n1.val>CA.val & n2.val>CA.val) CA=CA.right;
  else return CA;
 }
}`